# Ajax with long polling cannot display celery results on web pages

Tags: python, ajax, flask, celery, long-polling

I have a web page running on Flask, the user clicks the button then gives celery a long-running program. Ajax keeps polling to check if celery has output. If celery has a result, an alert will be displayed on the web page. Now if the program running in celery is very short, the alert can be displayed occasionally. If the program running in celery takes a long time, it cannot be displayed. And now the web page seems to be: click the button - alert - refresh the page in the order.

ubuntu 16.04, Chrome

the celery parts:

```
@celery.task(name='app.add')
def add():
    z=getLength()
    return {'result':z}

@app.route('/addit', methods=['POST'])
def addit():
    task = add.delay()
    return jsonify({}),202,{'Location': url_for('taskstatus',task_id=task.id)}

@app.route('/status/<task_id>')
def taskstatus(task_id):
    task = add.AsyncResult(task_id)
        if 'result' in task.info:
            response['result'] = task.info['result']
    return jsonify(response)
```

the ajax polling parts:

```
<script>
  function start_long_task() {
      $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: '/addit',
          success: function(data, status, request) {
              status_url = request.getResponseHeader('Location');
              update_progress(status_url) ;
          },
          error: function() {
              alert('Unexpected error');
          }
      });
  }
  function update_progress(status_url) {
      // send GET request to status URL
      $.getJSON(status_url, function(data) {
          if ('result' in data) {
              // show result
              alert('Result: ' + data['result']);
          }
          else {
              setTimeout(function() {
                  update_progress(status_url);
              }, 1000);
          }
      });
  }
  $(function() {
      $('#start-bg-job').click(start_long_task);
  });
</script>
```

The actual results may be that the webpages can show an alert when celery is done. But now it can't, please help me to fix this issue, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I found that if the button that performs the polling and the button that submits the form in the flask are the same, the webpage cannot display the alert. I just created a new button, dedicated to start ajax polling, so that it is successful, the web page can display alert!